# Unable to launch Android emulator on Azure Dv3 VM

Tags: android, azure, android-studio, android-virtual-device, azure-virtual-machine

I'm unable to launch emulator on Azure Dv3 VM. Here are the settings on my Windows 10 server.
Hyper-V disabled
Intel HAXM successfully installed.
**AVD settings**
Emulated Performance - Graphics - Software GLES 2.0 
Device Frame - Unchecked 

Getting the below error while launching emulator on VM.
[image: Emulation Engine Failed]

**Android Studio event logs display:** 
1. Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID 
2. Emulator: C:\Users\jenkadmin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'
3. Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

Based on some suggestions on SO I have enabled microphone access in Privacy settings and wipe(d) data and cold boot but nothing helps. 
Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you [enable hyper-v feature on the Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization#enable-the-hyper-v-feature-on-the-azure-vm)?

Comment: @NancyXiong - I disabled Hyper-V based on suggestions.